# Check in multiple columns for a range date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables with a column called `created` and the type as datetime.

I am looking for a way to check all the 3 created columns for a date (between today and today -7), if a date is found, the result should be 1 if not, 0.

This [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7554e/4) is what I have until now. It should return 1, but it is returning 0, instead.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN(
          (
            table1.created BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() AND
            table2.created BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() AND
            table3.created BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
          )
        )
    THEN
      1
    ELSE
      0
    END AS FLAG
FROM
  table1,
  table2,
  table3
WHERE
  table1.cond1= 'A' and
  table2.cond1= 'A' and
  table3.cond1= 'A'
```

Comment: In your SQL Fiddle link, the date that you have entered in the 3rd table does not lie between today and last 7 days range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a table has a row or rows matching a particular condition, you can use the [`EXISTS` predicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *  -- syntactically, the select list is disregarded here
                           -- meaning you can replace the "*" with anything else
                 FROM tablename
                 WHERE ...
                )
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
-- no FROM clause in the main SELECT
;
```

If you want to check simultaneously several tables, make that several predicates, like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...)
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ...)
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE ...)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
;
```

Finally, what other answerers have said also applies, i.e. you should consider changing your date checking conditions from

```
created BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

to

```
created BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

The original form would work too in your case but it would rely on implicit conversion of `int` to `datetime`, which is not a good practice and would break if you changed the type of `created` from `datetime` to one of the newer types, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` or, perhaps, `date`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `DATEDIFF` to `DATEADD` and `7` to `-7` and `AND` to `OR`:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN(
          (
            table1.created BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() OR
            table2.created BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() OR
            table3.created BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
          )
        )
    THEN
      1
    ELSE
      0
    END AS FLAG
FROM
  table1,
  table2,
  table3
WHERE
  table1.cond1= 'A' and
  table2.cond1= 'A' and
  table3.cond1= 'A'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/736a1/1)

Comment: The site is offline now. I was testing and it does not enter in the ELSE case, it always shows NULL.

Comment: Probably a fiddle error...as I see everything is deleted now. Try it in your code and see it there, also this query assumes that all 3 tables have a `cond1='A'`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, "today - 7" is `DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE())`.  What you have, `DATEDIFF(dd, 7, GETDATE())` is the difference between day 7 and today, measured in days.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to change that but the result still not coming.